# updateBadge in expandableitem in MaterialDrawer Android

Tags: android, badge, materialdrawer

I show a badge in the expandableItem. When the user click in that item, I want that the badge in the expandableItem disappeare and just show the badge in the subitem.
But in my code, when I do click, the badge disappear but the subitems are not shown. What I am doing wrong? 
Thanks.

```
result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(appbar)
            .withHasStableIds(true)
            .withAccountHeader(headerResult) 
            .addDrawerItems(
                    ...

                    new ExpandableBadgeDrawerItem().withName("Collapsable Badge").withIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_exp).withIdentifier(18).withSelectable(false).withBadge("2").withBadgeStyle(new BadgeStyle().withTextColor(Color.WHITE).withColorRes(R.color.md_red_700)).withSubItems(
                            new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("CollapsableItem").withLevel(2).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_send).withIdentifier(2000).withBadge("2").withBadgeStyle(new BadgeStyle().withTextColor(Color.WHITE).withColorRes(R.color.md_red_700)),
                            new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("CollapsableItem 2").withLevel(2).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_send).withIdentifier(2001)
                    )
            ) 
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {


                    if (drawerItem != null) {

                        if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 18) {
                            result.updateBadge(18, null);
                        }
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            })
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked it and you are right, it's basically a result of the way how the underlaying `FastAdapter` handle's expandable items, if the parent is updated it will collapse the child's. This will be improved in v3 of the `FastAdapter` until then please use the following snippet:

```
//get the item from our drawerItem
ExpandableBadgeDrawerItem d = (ExpandableBadgeDrawerItem) drawerItem;
//remove the badge
d.withBadge((StringHolder) null);
//notify the adapter that the item was changed
result.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(result.getPosition(18));
```